# finance.yahoo.com charts in Firefox makes 20.04 CRASH totally!

Tags: 20.04, firefox, yahoo

I tried using the procedure explained on https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en to report this problem. But that 'ubuntu-bug' command doesn't work either...

Description:

If I have 1 or 2 tabs in Firefox with financial charts like https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/GDXJ and I 'mess around' with them, suddenly Firefox AND Ubuntu 20.04 becomes totally unresponsive. The only thing that 'works' is the mouse cursor is moving. So I have to turn off the power on my laptop. I tried pressing a bunch of key combinations, and the only thing that happened was something called 'tty4' login...(?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Perhaps, ***perhaps*** you can see more information by remotely log in or using Ctrl-Alt-F3 to get a text terminal? I'll bet with "top" you see firefox consuming >100% of CPUs.